# How long is the Application-Scope valid in JSP?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, web-applications, scope

I'm using JSP for a Project and cache all the records from the database which are visible and editable for every user. For this purpose I use a Bean and set the scope to "application".

Its constructor includes the logic to fetch the data and works fine. If something is changed there are methods to take care about that. (NOT getter/setter)
Now it occurs always after I wait a specified time the constructor is called again and for some reason -I don't know yet- in that case the connection to the database fails. (Connection Time out on an MSSQL Server 2012)

I'm a bit puzzled about that. As I know as the scope is set to application it doesn't depend on the session or whatever any more.
On the other hand it might be the case I use the constructor in the wrong way. When is the constructor called if the scope is "application"? I'd say just once as the whole Application is used the first time. Am I wrong?

Comment: Till the application goes down !!!!

Comment: That's what I thought. I haven't restarted the application.
But why is then the constructor called again?